# MATLAB Motion Tracking and Data

Tags: matlab

I'm very new to coding, and need some help with a project of sorts. I have segments of video, and I need to be able to track the motion of an object(s) through these segments, and get data like a mapped path, average and instantaneous velocities, etc. I'm trying to do this in MATLAB, and have the 2016a version installed. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is an extremely complicated problem to take on as a new coder. Is there any smaller part of the problem you can take on? 

FWIW, if you're dead set on tackling this, you should look into the Matlab Computer Vision Toolbox.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing exactly what project you're working on, I can guess that Matlab is the wrong tool for this job.

I've been using Matlab near-daily for about four years now, but when I want to track an object in a video, I use [Tracker](http://physlets.org/tracker/).

Matlab is a good language for a beginning programmer because you can start doing numerical calculations, and plotting the results, very quickly. More advanced programmers tend to use Matlab to process data (Mathworks has many useful libraries for things like Fourier Transforms); to do linear algebra; to do quick numerical analyses; and to build scientific models. These applications are mainly in math, science, and engineering.

**If you want to learn Matlab,** I recommend you find a project which plays to Matlab's strengths.
**If you want to analyse images and videos**, I recommend that you learn a language which is used professionally for this purpose, such as Python or Java.